# Logitech K780 keyboard Windows 10 BT highlight text copy paste

Tags: windows, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

Fairly new Logitech K780 Bluetooth keyboard W10 (and Android) and loving it but I cannot find a map of what all the keys do. (no user manual shows) in particular how do I highlight some text, copy then paste in another page or site?

Thanks!

Comment: Keyboard model doesn't matter. Keypresses are interpreted by the operating system. All keyboards will work the same. This should make it easier to google your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [Logitech K780 Online Setup Guide](http://www.logitech.com/assets/64641/k780-online-setup-guide.pdf)<sup>1</sup> shows a list of all functions and shortcuts on page 6.

Copypasting text as well as highlighting is however OS dependent and is generally not a feature of the keyboard. On Windows you can copypaste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Selecting text is done by holding shift and moving the cursor around using either the arrow keys, home, end, pagedown or pageup.

<sub>1: Direct link to PDF, can be found by going to the [K780 product page](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/k780-multi-device-wireless-keyboard) and clicking on "Setup Guide".</sub>